# NodeJS creating File but without text

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey here is my little script:

```
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if(publicKey.startsWith(test[i])) {
            console.log(seed + " =[HIT]= " + publicKey)
            fs.appendFile(publicKey.toString() + '.txt', mnemonic.toString(), function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Finished!');
              });
              exit();

        } else {
            console.log(seed + " =[FAILED]= " + publicKey)
        }
    }
```

It does create my file but without any text? I tried to put in random text, but it did not work either. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` is synchronous, but `fs.writeFile` isn't. You are immediately launching several `fs.writeFile` at a time, all the commands are over even before your hard disk woke up and realised what happened.

Either use the synchronous version `fs.writeFileSync(...);` (not recommended), or use the Promise version and await it :

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';

for (let t of test) {
  if (publicKey.startsWith(t)) {
    console.log(seed + " =[HIT]= " + publicKey);
    await fs.appendFile(publicKey.toString() + '.txt', mnemonic.toString());
  } else {
    console.log(seed + " =[FAILED]= " + publicKey)
  }
}

console.log('Finished!');
process.exit();
```

Comment: May need `break` if the original intention was to write the first, and only the first, matching public key.

Comment: It worked thank you sir!